# How to get liked video filtered by videoCategoryId with Youtube api

Tags: node.js, youtube, google-api, youtube-api

i want to get my liked youtube video obly for the category id 10 (music). So i test with this code:

```
 youtube.videos.list({
                auth: oauth, part: 'snippet', 
                myRating:'like', maxResults:50,
                chart:'mostPopular', regionCode:'FR',
                videoCategoryId:req.params.categoryId
               }, 
               function(err, response) {
                    ...
               }
 );
```

The response is 'Incompatible parameters specified in the request.' because according to [this doc](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/docs/videos/list#chart), 'Filters (specify exactly one of the following parameters)' i can't user the filter 'chart' with 'myRating'.

So how can i get me liked video only for the category Music, without get all my liked video and filter manually. Thank's

Answer (score 0):

This is not possible with the current API. like what you have researched you can only specify one Filter between chart, id and myRating. And videoCategoryId as stated below can only be used in conjunction with chart

> The videoCategoryId parameter identifies the video category for which the chart should be retrieved. This parameter can only be used in conjunction with the chart parameter. By default, charts are not restricted to a particular category. The default value is 0.